# Regular expression to get the section value from a URL

Tags: regex

From the below url i need to search only the section part from it.

Section is **news** here,

```
http://www.insight.co.kr/news/155252
```

I tried the below regex, but i seriously doubt that i am anywhere near the  right expression.

```
(.*\/)(.+)(\/.+)
```

Comment: Your pattern [looks  working](https://regex101.com/r/3ka0As/1), grab Group 2

Comment: This question might benefit from more information like: What programming language are the regular expressions from?  Is the host (or any other part of the url) always `insight.co.kr`? Whether there can be more than one subdirectory (e.g.  `abc.co.kr/lastest/news/123`) in the path and what is the desired output then? Apart from that I agree with Wiktor, that your regular expression is probably correct for the given example (but maybe not as robust as Badro's answer).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  How do i grab Group 2 ?

Comment: With the language means.

Answer (score 0):

In order to select the section part of the given URL

> http://www.insight.co.kr/news/155252

I would suggest the following solution:

```
 ^\w+://[^/]+/([^/]+)/.*$
```

- The `\w+` for the protocol https or https.
- `://` what comes after the protocol
- `[^/]+` for the domain name with the extension, we select everything till the next /.
- For `([^/]+)` that's your section, it's represent everything till the next / & the `()` to capture the selection.
- The `.*` will select the rest of the URL.

If you have any further questions please do not hesitate to ask

Comment: What if i want to match the first word after the domain url (excluding http://www.insight.co.kr/ and /155252 of the url)

Comment: @monikasatheesh I have edited my answer, I added .* in order to select the last part of the URL, for matching the first word after the "insight.co.kr" you can simply compare the capture.